# jQuery - bouncing effect without changing object's position on screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bounce

Not sure if my html and/or css would be needed to find the issue but I've been calling the bounce effect on images when clicked and it completely changes their position on the screen before/during the bounce. Not sure why this is? I have:

```
$('img').click(function() {
        $(this).effect('bounce', {times:3}, 300);
});
```

With images to the right of other divs (including inputs) and the jump to the bottom middle of the screen for their bouncing

edit: here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ep6wG/1/ (images should bounce)

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Can you put this code into a `jsFiddle` or something similar to see the problem ?

Comment: Ah good idea forgot about that! http://jsfiddle.net/ep6wG/
edit: sorry here is right link http://jsfiddle.net/ep6wG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/nmy3V/

You can set css like this.

```
#content {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:100px 0 0 0;
    background:red;
}
#content img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
}
#content input {
    float:left;
    margin:50px 0 0 120px;
}
#content div {
    float:left;
    margin:100px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hhmm I'm using floats/margins in my CSS but not positions, can that affect it? Forgot to originally add my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ep6wG/1/

Comment: yes, if you dont use position for bounce object, the layout will effect. Use float/margin as usual, but the bounce object, try to use position, as in my example.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, and it apparently can still mess up under position: relative so do you have to use absolute?

Comment: yes, only position absolute doesnt affect the layout, so use float for the whole div, including image you want to bounce, then, use float and margin for the rest elements that are within div.